# Determine $\lim _{z \to 0}\frac {e^{-1/z}}{z}$ =?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

It appears to be $0$.

But the classical L'Hôpital does not work because we end up with pretty much the same:
$\lim _{z \to 0}\dfrac {e^{\frac {-1}{z}}}{z^2}$ ....

Comment: You had better be taking the limit $z \to 0^+$. It's usually dealt with by changing variable, $w = 1/z$ and taking the limit $w \to +\infty$.

Comment: essential singularity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit, but to be fun I'll explain what's left of it with non-standard. 
As z approaches 0 from all directions we get $${e^{-1/z} \over z}={e^{-sgn(0)\epsilon} \over sgn(0)\epsilon}=sgn(0) \omega e^{sgn(0)\omega}$$
note $$\omega=e^{ln\omega}$$
substitute, knowing that $\epsilon$ is a really small number and $\omega$ is its inverse
we'll get $$sgn(0) \omega e^{sgn(0)\epsilon}=sgn(0)e^{ln{(w)}+sgn(0)\omega}$$
Staying with real signs, make sgn(0) equal to -1 or 1 and you'll see how this limit doesn't exist, but can actually be 0 or $\pm$ infinity. This actually excludes more exotic signs, which occur when you approach from the complex plane. These other limits are omitted, but know they exist.

Comment: Actually, every $\omega \in \mathbb C$ with at most a single exception will be a limit :D

Comment: can you explain ? why for exmaple 0 will be a limit ?

Comment: I had used $\omega$ as essentially infinity. We still agree though, this limit can be anything, so it doesn't exist.